# Java sorting elements of ArrayList and giving all of the information about a given object as an output

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have created an array in which the integer numbers represent the person's age, and I need them sorted in ascending order, except that I also need for an output to show their other information too (name and last name).

```
ArrayList<ClassName> list = new ArrayList<>();
ClassName c1 = new ClassName("Name", "LastName", 35);
ClassName c2 = new ClassName("Name", "LastName", 23);
list.add(c1);
list.add(c2);
System.out.println(list);
```

I used Collections for sorting in this way:

```
ArrayList<ClassName> list = new ArrayList<>();
ClassName c1 = new ClassName("Name", "LastName", 35);
ClassName c2 = new ClassName("Name", "LastName", 23);
list.add(c1);
list.add(c2);
System.out.println(list); //for showing the whole info

//then i made another array because i needed the sort by integers
ArrayList<Integer> sort = new ArrayList<>(); 
sort.add(c1.age);
sort.add(c2.age);
Collections.sort(sort);
System.out.println("Sorting: " + sort);
```

Okay so this method will only give me a list of objects before sorting and an `Sorting: [23, 35]` as an output. But what I need is the full information in order, so what I actually need as an output is this:

```
Name: Name
Last name: LastName
Age: 23

Name: Name
Last name: LastName
Age: 35
```

Not the full list and then separate sorting elements. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want this：

```
Name: Name
Last name: LastName
Age: 23

Name: Name
Last name: LastName
Age: 35
```

you should Override the `toString` method of the class `ClassName`

like this

```
public String toString() {                                                                                                                                             
    return "Name: " + this.name + "\n" + "Last name: " + this.lastName + "\n" + "Age:" + this.age + "\n";              
}
```

and use for loop to print that:

```
ArrayList<ClassName> list = new ArrayList<>();
ClassName c1 = new ClassName("Name", "LastName", 35);
ClassName c2 = new ClassName("Name", "LastName", 23);
list.add(c1);
list.add(c2);
//System.out.println(list); //for showing the whole info
for ( int i = 0, len = list.size(); i < len; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}

ArrayList<Integer> sort = new ArrayList<>(); //then i made another array because i needed the sort by integers
sort.add(c1.age);
sort.add(c2.age);
Collections.sort(sort);
System.out.println("Sorting: " + sort);
```

---

**Below is the original wrong answer**

I ran your code and the result is normal, but it contains an error when i try to compile：

```
error: cannot find symbol
ArrayList<Integer> sort = new Arraylist<>(); //then i made another array because i needed the sort by integers
                                  ^
```

This will get a compile exception,I guess, when you wrote the following code, it compiled and ran once：

```
ArrayList<ClassName> list = new ArrayList<>();
ClassName c1 = new ClassName("Name", "LastName", 35);
ClassName c2 = new ClassName("Name", "LastName", 23);
list.add(c1);
list.add(c2);
System.out.println(list); //for showing the whole info
```

When you add the following code, you try to run it again, but the compilation fails, and the class file obtained from the last compilation is used when running：

```
ArrayList<Integer> sort = new Arraylist<>(); 
sort.add(c1.age);
sort.add(c2.age);
Collections.sort(sort);
System.out.println("Sorting: " + sort);
```

you should write like this: `ArrayList<Integer> sort = new ArrayList<>();` , `new ArrayList()` not `new Arraylist`

For me it's like this, and it get that `Sorting: [23, 35]`.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I stated that "Sorting: [23, 35]" is not the output I want. The output I want is explained below that.

Comment: @megami oh sorry，My English is not very good, I overlooked some semantics, I re-look at the code LoL;